# list of lists and i can't seem to get the indent right

Tags: python, indentation

Now there's no indent error:

```
def best_wild_hand(hand):
  #Try all values for jokers in all 5-card selections.
  blackJoker= "?B"
  redJoker = "?R"


  dictSuit = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14 }
  listofLists = []

  if blackJoker in hand:

    newHand = hand.remove(blackJoker)
    for d in dictSuit:
      listofLists.append(newHand.append(d + "S"))
    return listofLists
```

I am trying to get a list of lists where if blackJoker is found in the hand parameter list that is being passed in to best_wild_hand method. If a black hand is found we remove it and append 2..13 + C(all the clover cards found in a deck) to the hand. I am trying to make a list of hands that includes 1 clover(so a list of hands + nC) n being a number 2- 13

My expected output is list of lists which has 2C...13C in each list which replaces the black poker

NO MORE ERROR but when i run in this print statement code doesn't return anything bu an error

```
print best_wild_hand(['6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC', '5C', '?B'])
```

Comment: Use any editor or IDE which enforces indentation. Make your problem disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edited to match *your* edit

Your issue is that you are assigning a variable to a method. This is causing the variable to be `None`:

```
>>> y = ['6C'].remove('6C')
>>> print y
None
>>>
```

Instead, change

```
newHand = hand.remove(blackJoker)
```

To

```
newHand = hand
newHand.remove(blackJoker)
```

As such:

```
def best_wild_hand(hand):
  #Try all values for jokers in all 5-card selections.
  blackJoker= "?B"
  redJoker = "?R"


  dictSuit = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14 }
  listofLists = []

  if blackJoker in hand:

    newHand = hand
    newHand.remove(blackJoker)
    for d in dictSuit:
      listofLists.append(newHand.append(d + "S"))
    return listofLists
```

Now when I run your code:

```
bash-3.2$ python safd.py
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
bash-3.2$
```

<sup>Perhaps *not* what you wanted, but it's printing nonetheless</sup>

Comment: what was your output? ccould you share please?

Comment: I didn't get an output, I just pasted your function in.

Comment: youre rihght i just can't seem to figure out why the print statement is not returning anything it supposed to return list of lists

Comment: thanks @A.J  i think i have to make list() function to actually form a list but yes that could be solved !!

Comment: @Purple_haze, if this haloed you, would you mind clicking on the green check next to my answer (to accept it), you get reputation too!

Comment: Thanks was waiting if anyone else could chime with anything else